# Using Match to return column number

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to use .Match to identify the column value which searching a row.

Basically, I have 3 worksheets, each with different headings, and I am looking to identify which headings are the same from each sheet, in order to compare the data.

This is the code that I have so far (it is only a PoC at the moment):

```
Sub aaaa()

Dim a As Double
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Variant
Dim e As Variant
Dim f As Variant
Dim h As Double

Worksheets("Reconciliation").Activate

Columns.Select
Selection.ClearContents

a = 1
h = 2

While Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, 1) <> vbNullString

    b = 1
    c = 1
    d = vbNullString
    e = vbNullString
    f = vbNullString

    While Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, 1) <> vbNullString

        If a = 1 Then
            Cells(h, b) = Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c)
            Cells(h, b + 1) = Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c) & "_CUMIS"

            d = WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c), Worksheets("MAddress").Rows("1:1"), 0)

            If Not IsError(d) Then

                Cells(h - 1, b + 1) = d

            ElseIf IsError(d) Then

                d = WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c), Worksheets("Member_Details").Rows(1), 0)
                Cells(h - 1, b + 1) = "M" & d

            End If

            b = b + 2
            c = c + 1

        Else
            Cells(h, b) = Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c)

            If b = 1 Then
                e = WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c), Worksheets("MAddress").Range("A:A"), 0)


                If Not IsError(e) And Not IsError(d) Then

                    Cells(a, b + 1) = Worksheets("MAddress").Cells(d, e)

                Else
                End If
            End If



        End If

    Wend

    a = a + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

When I dun it, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '9': Subscription out of range
```

Any suggestions on how I can search a row for a variable value, and return the column number>

Comment: you can use `Find` function

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Which line produces the  "Run-time error '9': Subscription out of range"

Comment: d=Worksheetfunction.match....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test d with IsError(d) then you have to use d = application.match(...), not d = worksheetFunction.match(...).

```
        d = Application.Match(Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c), Worksheets("MAddress").Rows("1:1"), 0)

        If Not IsError(d) Then
            Cells(h - 1, b + 1) = d
        Else
            d = Application.Match(Worksheets("Cleanse").Cells(a, c), Worksheets("Member_Details").Rows(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(d) Then
                Cells(h - 1, b + 1) = "M" & d
            end if
        End If
        ...
```

Comment: It's still returning the same error after the change

Comment: Then you have more than a single problem. WorksheetFunction will not produce a result that can be tested with IsError.

Comment: Think the issue is around the .Match being used on a Row. Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: No, I use similar code all the time. Did you change the e matches to application.match as well/